# Sage theme caching issue on WPEngine

Tags: cache, nginx

I have experienced an issue on WPEngine servers when deploying a Sage.io theme. The issue manifests as a persistent cache after copying the site from one environment to another where data/content changes appear to migrate but changes to blade templates do not.

In this instance the WPEngine server has GES (cloudflare) WAF/Caching in place but no other cache plugins are used.

There is a lot of conversation about this at https://discourse.roots.io/t/sage-9-on-wpengine/9090/6 but our fix after much ado was pretty simple.

The default path for cache creation in Sage is set to create files in themedirectory/uploads/cache in /config/view.php (around line 32)

Changing this line to 'compiled' => '/tmp/sage-cache', seems to solve the problem and may even put that cache in a place where it can be cleared with the WPE Utility.

So now my question: Has anyone else experienced this and what did you do to resolve it if different? Mostly just documenting for a future troubleshooter.